# C# locking away SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have encountered a problem with getting locked out of SQLite file. 
I am currently working on employee register for my company and use SQLite as a database of choice. From my program, I populated the database using scripts I prepared. Reading goes well and all, but once I make any change to the employee at all, the program freezes at "database is locked" exception. 
I created a static class called SQLiteManager where I have all methods involving the DB. I then call them from Windows Forms like

```
foreach (Employee em in SQLiteManager.getEmployees()){
 //filling the fields }
```

calls

```
public static List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        List<Employee> ret = new List<Employee>();
        SQLiteDataReader reader;
        using (SQLiteConnection dbc = new SQLiteConnection(databaseConnectionString))
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = dbc.CreateCommand())
        {
            openConnection(dbc);
            cmd.CommandText = "select ID_Employee from Employee";
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read()) { ret.Add(extractEmployee(reader["ID_Employee"].ToString(), false)); }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

I always use this "using" notations in ALL other methods that call ExecuteReader() in them.

Method that I use to crunch the script and populate the DB:

```
public static bool processSqlCommandFile(string file)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    using (SQLiteConnection dbc = new SQLiteConnection(databaseConnectionString))
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = dbc.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        openConnection(dbc);
                        cmd.CommandText = line;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and finally, the sore method

```
public static bool alterEmployee(Employee e) {
         using (SQLiteConnection dbc = new SQLiteConnection(databaseConnectionString))
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = dbc.CreateCommand())
        {
            openConnection(dbc);
            cmd.CommandText = "Update Employee SET name = '"+e.name+"' where ID_Employee = "+e.id;
//Alter the command once this shiet works
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Yet it always gets frozen. By using the using(SQLiteConnection...) I thought I am getting rid of the "sleepy" connections that would somehow lock it, but the trouble is somewhere else.

Can you help me identify the problem or tell me steps to identify it myself?

Thank you

Comment: What does the method extractEmployee do? If it selects from the db again, i assume you have a nice locked resource over there...

Comment: ye, it tooks the One exact employee based on PK (the id field).

Comment: How does the alterEmployee method fit in the story? It's not used in the example code. (+ it might be a bit overkill to start a new connection for every line in the processSqlCommandFile method)

Comment: story behind AlterEmployee: I show up all the employee's details in windows form (separate textboxes for properties). Those textboxes are editable and clicking the Save button runs following code:  
    
    private void btnDatabaseWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SQLiteManager.alterEmployee(lbCompany.SelectedItem as Employee);
        }

which pretty much takes info from these fields, munches them into one employee instance and feeds it to the method

Comment: @TimEeckhaut Thanks a lot for your help. The double locking in ExtractEmployee was the problem I just did not see every time I went over. You are right with the overkilling, I just went into "overkill" mode when the problems started, time for refactoring is now. Thanks again, you saved my hide